# What logical fallacy is "The Sun is very hard to look at, therefore there are no reliable witnesses of its existence."?

Tags: logic, fallacies

What logical fallacy is "*The Sun is very hard to look at, therefore there are no reliable witnesses of its existence.*" or "*A massacre is very hard to look at, therefore there are no reliable witnesses that Vukovar Massacre occurred.*"?

Comment: Not to mention non-biological instruments, apparently, if something extremely bright so that a seer's eyes will be burned and completely damaged upon seeing, it's obvious at least this witness can *reliably* claim something emergent exists from said experience. Of course in most everyday cases. if something is very hard to detect (looked at), it may be hard to find reliable witness. Thus the main fallacy could be [Appeal to probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_probability): *the logical fallacy of taking something for granted because it would probably be the case*...

Comment: Maybe "fallacy" is too noble a world... For sure, no "logic" at all. It is simply the point of view of [Modern Flat-Earthers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_flat_Earth_beliefs): I haven't seen it, therefore it is not true.

Comment: See also [Historical negationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_negationism). As per many others similar posts, we have to avoid calling "logical fallacies" what are simply errors, fakes, lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of what is called the fallacy of overlooking alternatives (see [Weston, The Two Basic Fallacies](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24435524), a special case of [false dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) is most popular): if *one* (or several) ways of observing the Sun are "hard", and hence unreliable, then *no* way is reliable. However, these examples display fundamental lack of imagination as the cause of such overlooking, and are similar to the [argument from incredulity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_incredulity) (*ad incredulitatem*), a.k.a. appeal to common sense: something is impossible because it is hard to see how it can be done (given one's background knowledge, expectations, common sense, etc.).

The OP examples are quite blunt in this regard as they do not pass even minimal scrutiny of such incredulity. But lack of imagination can be much more subtle and understandable, and conclusions based on it not unreasonable in many contexts. Like all informal fallacies this one blends into valid informal reasoning, which may, nonetheless, turn out to be fallible. Indeed, we all have to rely on such reasoning at times in assessing what is possible or feasible. COVID pandemic gives plenty of examples.

There are several famous historical examples of this too. Kant's opinion, which he elevated to an *a priori* dogma, that no geometry is possible other than Euclidean geometry and no mechanics other than Newtonian mechanics. It did not seem implausible in his time. Du Bois Reymond's pronounced his [*ignoramus et ignorabimus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoramus_et_ignorabimus) (we do not know and will never know) in 1872 over "seven world riddles" inaccessible to science, which became an idiom for this sort of thing. [Pessimistic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessimistic_induction), which some consider a fallacy, is a derivative of that frame of mind. Hilbert countered it with his optimistic "*in opposition to the foolish ignorabimus our slogan shall be: we must know — we will know*". But... du Bois Reymond's riddles included the nature of consciousness and free will, and many would side with him on those even today.

Here is one more example, which illustrates the subtleties. Comte (the father of classical positivism) opined in 1835 that chemical composition of the stars will never be known because the stars are too far away for us to reach, see [Hearnshaw, Auguste Comte's blunder](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2010JAHH...13...90H):

> "*We understand the possibility of determining their
> shapes, their distances, their sizes and their movements;
> whereas we would never know how to study by any
> means their chemical composition, or their mineralogical structure, and, even more so, the nature of any
> organized beings that might live on their surface... I persist in the opinion that every notion of the true mean temperatures of the stars will necessarily always be concealed from us.*"

At the time of Comte's writing Fraunhofer already initiated spectral analysis of starlight, which, after a hundred years, led to proving Comte wrong on one point, and current investigations of exoplanets may eventually prove him wrong on the other. However, as Hearnshaw notes,

> "*However, upon reflection, it seems like an excusable error. Evidently he believed the stars to be so far away (no observed parallax was published until 1838) that there appeared to be no possibility of ever going to the stars to carry out a chemical analysis or to measure their temperatures*".

Comment: Kant was right about geometry and you are exaggerating his views on mechanics. Kant didn't claim that it was impossible to create a consistent geometry-like theory based on a different family of curves other than straight lines.

Comment: @DavidGudeman The idea of "consistent geometry" and the like is a modernization that presupposes post-Kantian view of logic. Kant did not even think of possibility in such terms, see e.g. Friedman, Kant and Exact Sciences:"*Kant's conception of logic is not that of modern quantification theory, and he can have no notion like ours of all logically possible structures... a non-Euclidean structure would have to possess the topological properties (denseness and continuity) common to Euclidean and non-Euclidean spaces, and this, for Kant, is impossible.*"

Comment: So Kant didn't know about topological properties but he would have thought they are impossible? I don't buy it. Of course Kant didn't understand mathematical logic, that's my point. He wasn't making a claim about mathematical logic; he was claiming that Euclid's postulates are true descriptions of our experience of space (not necessarily our sensory impressions, but our overall experience). And he was right. The only thing the non-Euclidean logics proved is that the fifth postulate is independent, but that is perfectly consistent with Kant's claims.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Kant's conception of geometry was much more than "our experience of space", he was not  psychologistic, and his conceptions of logic and possibility were quite different as well. He did not have what is now called "logical possibility" and "logical independence" did not have any sense at the time. These "he was right about [modern something]" "defenses" of Kant are historically oblivious and sell Kant short, again, see Friedman. He was wrong, but he had good and non-trivial reasons to be wrong, not "right" under some diluted modern contrivances.

Comment: It's like you aren't reading what I'm writing. I didn't say Kant was right about anything involving modern logic. I specifically denied that. The point I was making in modern logic terms is that non-Euclidean geometry is irrelevant to Kant's position because Kant never claimed the fifth postulate was inferable from the others. Also, any brief description of Kant's views on space and time can be misinterpreted as psychologism by a hostile reader. You have done this before. I wish you would stop.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I get the same impression from you. Your objections are based on underinformed secondary literature, and the last comment is unrelated to my point. Since we are talking past each other let's stop.

Comment: I've read A Critique of Pure Reason, Prolegomena, and one or two other works of Kant, along with a variety of critiques and explications of Kant by professional philosophers. I've also read most of Berkeley's work, a lot of Hume, Whitehead, Duhem, and Frege, and dozens, if not hundreds of works by other professional philosophers and logicians (including people writing against the above named writers). You are confusing a novel viewpoint with a lack of familiarity with the subject matter.